# using SVG from sprite in a background

Tags: html, css, svg

My goal is to use `SVG` in repeated background, but I need to be able to change its `fill` color in `CSS` for usage in the different parts of the website.

As far as my understanding of the `SVG`, it can't be laoded as an external file (`background:url(image.svg)`), because then I am not able to change the `CSS` property like `fill` proeprty of it. On the other hand, `SVG` can't be inlined in `HTML` (`<svg>...</svg>`) as then I am not able to use/reference it in `background` property.

Please correct me if I am wrong, or do you have any solution for this?

Comment: you could construct the entire SVG via javascript dynamically, convert it to a data URL and use that as a background.

Comment: svg can be an external file and svg can definitely be inline ..<-- that's only my opinion ..Please wait for others

Comment: @Amit sure it can be both, but how about the fill property change in CSS?

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, but not sure how that would help me. Do you mean to generate it more times with the same JS code, but different fill for each?

Comment: sure, if that's what you need.

Comment: @RobertLongson ok, so no pure css/html solution for this if I would need to change the fill on hover or so?

Comment: Sure there is, have two backgrounds and swap on hover.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks. The whole point was to use the code only once and only change the proeprties in css. So I guess the JS is the only way here

Comment: so don't use a background at all, use inline SVG

Comment: @RobertLongson sure I would, if I would not need to use it repeatedly. for example 100 stars in a row. Then my goal is to have one star in SVG (save trasfered data) and use repeat-x.

Comment: use a pattern if the stars are identical.

Comment: Have a look at https://css-doodle.com/ If only for inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as my understanding of the SVG, it can't be laoded as an
> external file (background:url(image.svg)), because then I am not able
> to change the CSS property like fill proeprty of it.

Consider using [CSS filters](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#interpolation-of-filter-functions) to change svg coloration instead of `fill`

In the example below the svg file is loaded as an external file:

`background-image:url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg);`

and its color will be changed on hover using a combination of css filters

You can get the desired combination of filters for a specific color using the utility

https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

[image]

*Hover to change color*

```css
.android {
display:inline-block;
width:96px;
height:105px;
background-image:url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg);
}
.android.blue:hover {
 filter: invert(8%) sepia(99%) saturate(7454%) hue-rotate(248deg) brightness(100%) contrast(143%);
} 

.android.red:hover {
 filter: invert(25%) sepia(100%) saturate(7420%) hue-rotate(6deg) brightness(98%) contrast(122%);
} 

.android.gold:hover {
 filter: invert(50%) sepia(31%) saturate(3357%) hue-rotate(113deg) brightness(99%) contrast(101%);
}
```

```html
<div class="android blue">
</div>
<div class="android red">
</div>
<div class="android gold">
</div>
```

Comment: ok. first I thought about it as a workaround, more than solution and expected either pure svg way, or answer like "no it is not possible". but in the end, if this is the only way, then for future visitors, it can be hilighted as a solution. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it's not super simple but, it can be done with some work to the SVG itself. if you look at the simple example you will see inside the  tag under the  you can essentially make a pattern of any SVG elements like a circle,rect, or a path.
**So make the pattern as**

```html
<pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
```

make sure the  **width** and **height** are the **same as your SVG** or it will cut it off

then outside of the defs you can make a rect object with the fill of your pattern `fill="url(#dots)"` this must use the id of the pattern

**Simple example**

```css
.pattern {
  background-color: #2e4057;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="pattern">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                 
                <circle fill="#bee9e8" cx="50" cy="50" r="25">
                </circle>
                 
            </pattern>
        </defs>
         
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#dots)"></rect>
</div>
```

**More advanced SVG**

```css
.pattern {
  background-color: #2e4057;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="pattern">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="duck" x="0" y="0" width="209" height="209" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <g>
                    <path fill="red" d="M105.572,101.811c9.889-6.368,27.417-16.464,28.106-42.166c0.536-20.278-9.971-49.506-49.155-50.878
                        C53.041,7.659,39.9,28.251,36.071,46.739l-0.928-0.126c-1.932,0-3.438,1.28-5.34,2.889c-2.084,1.784-4.683,3.979-7.792,4.308
                        c-3.573,0.361-8.111-1.206-11.698-2.449c-4.193-1.431-6.624-2.047-8.265-0.759c-1.503,1.163-2.178,3.262-2.028,6.226
                        c0.331,6.326,4.971,18.917,16.016,25.778c7.67,4.765,16.248,5.482,20.681,5.482c0.006,0,0.006,0,0.006,0
                        c2.37,0,4.945-0.239,7.388-0.726c2.741,4.218,5.228,7.476,6.037,9.752c2.054,5.851-27.848,25.087-27.848,55.01
                        c0,29.916,22.013,48.475,56.727,48.475h55.004c30.593,0,70.814-29.908,75.291-92.48C180.781,132.191,167.028,98.15,105.572,101.811
                        z M18.941,77.945C8.775,71.617,4.992,58.922,5.294,55.525c0.897,0.24,2.194,0.689,3.228,1.042
                        c4.105,1.415,9.416,3.228,14.068,2.707c4.799-0.499,8.253-3.437,10.778-5.574c0.607-0.509,1.393-1.176,1.872-1.491
                        c0.87,0.315,0.962,0.693,1.176,3.14c0.196,2.26,0.473,5.37,2.362,9.006c1.437,2.761,3.581,5.705,5.646,8.542
                        c1.701,2.336,4.278,5.871,4.535,6.404c-0.445,1.184-4.907,3.282-12.229,3.282C30.177,82.591,23.69,80.904,18.941,77.945z
                         M56.86,49.368c0-4.938,4.001-8.943,8.931-8.943c4.941,0,8.942,4.005,8.942,8.943c0,4.931-4.001,8.942-8.942,8.942
                        C60.854,58.311,56.86,54.299,56.86,49.368z M149.159,155.398l-20.63,11.169l13.408,9.293c0,0-49.854,15.813-72.198-6.885
                        c-11.006-11.16-13.06-28.533,4.124-38.84c17.184-10.312,84.609,3.943,84.609,3.943L134.295,147.8L149.159,155.398z"/>
                </g>                         
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#duck)"></rect>
    </svg>
```

**hope this helps**

a more complete tutorial [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-svg-patterns-as-backgrounds--cms-31507)

Comment: tahnk you for that example, but still I don't see an option to change the fill of elements (ducks here)

Comment: you can change the fill of the path itself ill edit the snippet to show you

Comment: or you can give the path a class/id and add the fill in your css file

Comment: I believe this example is static. That means you can change the color, but can not change for multiple use of the same svg. In another words I still can't see the option to reuse the svg and change the fill on the go